# setTimeout calls function repeatedly and causes page to hang

Tags: spring-mvc

I have three javascript functions defined that creates ajax calls to my java controller. I set timeouts for two of the functions to update the ping status every 3 seconds and to update performance status every 5 min. The ping update every 3 seconds seems to be working correctly but when the updatePerformance method gets called my controller method gets executed 5 or so times in a row until the app hangs. Any ideas why one is working and the other setTimeout isn't? Here's my javascript functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function updateReachability() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'updatePing.htm',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#site').html(data);
        }
    });
}
setTimeout(updateReachability, 3000);

function updatePerformance() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'updatePerformance.htm',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#site').html(data);
        }
    });
}
setTimeout(updatePerformance, 300000);

function updateSiteList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'connector.htm',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#site').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to wrap you function in the setTimeout itself, so that the settimeout is specific to that function and nothing else.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function updateReachability() {
    setTimeout(function() {
$.ajax({
        url: 'updatePing.htm',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#site').html(data);
        }
    });
},3000);
```

May be this will work for you.

Comment: tried that and still calls the method multiple times. It looks like it waits the 5 minutes then fires off a bunch of the ajax calls and never stops

Comment: good point @edom13,setTimeout will be triggered after certain amount of time, and thats what i thought ur expectation was, but you can use .delay() function from jquery itself to delay the things, so it would be                              [code]$.ajax({
        url: 'updatePing.htm',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#site').html(data);
        }
    }).delay(5000); [/code]

Comment: I am expecting it to wait 5 min then fire one ajax call to my updatePerformance.htm URL which calls an updatePerformance() method in my controller. Then wait another 5 minutes and call this method again. But what it seems to be doing is waiting 5 minutes then calling the updatePerformance() method 5 times in a row then calling it again 5 or 6 times in a row. I am tracking this by having a print statement in my controller method to see how many times the view calls it.

Comment: thanks for the info @chetank, It looks like the issue is with having the two timeout values set because when I remove the 3 second timeout and just have the timeout set on the function every 5 minutes it works fine. So there must be some kind of collision when having both timeouts set

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why this works but created a separate function that sets the two timeout values then called it on body onload:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function updateSiteList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'connector.htm',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#site').html(data);
        }
    });
}

function updateReachability() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'updatePing.htm',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#site').html(data);
        }
    });
}

function setTimeouts() {
setInterval(updateReachability, 3000);
setInterval(updatePerformance, 300000);
}

function updatePerformance() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'updatePerformance.htm',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#site').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```